# IntelliJ ignores Breakpoints in Groovy Scripts

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, groovy

I tried to debug a groovy script, but the debugger just ignored all breakpoints I set. It happens in every groovy script, even simple ones just containing 3 print commands.
In Java files debugger is working as expected, stopping on breakpoints, showing variable values, ...

I searched for a solution, but Google came up with many hits that were either several years old, are different from my problem or provide solutions without proper explanation for me since I'm not that familiar with IntelliJ.

I checked the Log and found these lines:

```
2018-09-26 11:44:45,240 [ 975199]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar 
2018-09-26 11:44:45,391 [ 975350]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
2018-09-26 11:44:45,391 [ 975350]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
2018-09-26 11:44:45,391 [ 975350]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

So I guess I miss smth. like a DebuggerClass for Groovy, any idea of how to add one?

Comment: Do you debug file via right click menu creating a new debug configuration? Have you checked idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") for errors?

Comment: No, I used the default Debug Configurations set by IntelliJ. I add Logs to the opening post.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project for investigation?

Comment: Well, in a completely new project the debugger works. I can't share the 'corrupted' one since it contains much sensitive data. But I copy pasted the whole code into a new project, so the problem is solved for me.